# The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred - PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a php script file that takes information from a form and places it into a sql database, after the script finishes I force the browser to be redirected to another web page.

When running this script locally, it works as it should.. taking the information putting it into the database and redirecting to aboutus.html. However on my server, it also does what it is supposed to do by taking the typed in information and inserting it into the database, but instead of the browser being redirected, it brings up a plain white page with the words:

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

No error number; nothing. I have a

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

to report any errors, but it doesn't specify what it is. By following my code and sense the data is physically put into the database it obviously runs through that section of code without any error, but once it hits the portion of code to redirect the browser, it fails.. Here is my section of code to illustrate.

```
if(""!=trim($_POST["spFirstName"])){
    $host = //taken out for security reasons;
    $user = //taken out for security reasons;
    $pass = //taken out for security reasons;
    $db = //taken out for security reasons;
    //connect to database
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);      //connects to database

    if (!$con){    
        die("Connection failed: " .my_sqli_connect_err());
    }

    //Spirit Vars - reformats data from previous form

    $firstName =  ucwords(strtolower($_POST["spFirstName"]));
    $firstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $firstName);

    $lastName =  ucwords(strtolower($_POST["spLastName"]));
    $lastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $lastName);

    $email =  $_POST["spEmail"];
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $email);

    $spComment =  htmlspecialchars($_POST['spComment']);
    $spComment = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $spComment);


    $findEmail = "SELECT * FROM notAttending WHERE email='" . $email."'";
    $results = mysqli_query($con, $findEmail);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0){
        echo "Looks like you have already let us know that you won't be attending! Thanks for being with us in spirit! Any questions please email us at duanannari@gmail.com :)";
    }
    else{
        //create SQL statement to create new row;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO notAttending (spFirstName, spLastName, spEmail, spComment) VALUES ('".$firstName."', '".$lastName."',  '".$email."',  '".$spComment."');";


        // This is where I believe the code doesn't work?? Maybe??

        if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
            header("Location: http://www.uyswedding.com/aboutus.html");
        }
        else{
           echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
        }
    }

}
```

Now to add a little more confusion to the pile, I actually have the same code as above in the same script file (.php) that deals with different data depending on whether the user entered certain fields or not.

This form is for a wedding so either the user can rsvp or 'not attend' depending on which path the user takes this script file will direct the data to the proper table in the database..

So if someone 'rsvps' and hits enter. The data is put in the database and redirected to a web page.. However if someone fills out the 'not attending' it gives me this error.

That being said.. I had no problem with this script 3 months ago, and I haven't intentionally made any changes since then. The website has been in limbo since then.. I will add the entire php file under all this text so the above description makes more sense. Thank you!

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(""!=trim($_POST["FirstName"])){
    $host = //taken out for security reasons;
    $user = //taken out for security reasons;
    $pass = //taken out for security reasons;
    $db = //taken out for security reasons;

    //connect to database
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

if (!$con){
    die("Connection failed: " .my_sqli_connect_err());
}

//Spirit Vars
$firstName =  ucwords(strtolower($_POST["FirstName"]));
$firstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $firstName);

//Person Vars
$firstName =  ucwords(strtolower($_POST["FirstName"]));
$firstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $firstName);

$lastName =   ucwords(strtolower($_POST["LastName"]));
$lastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $lastName);


$guestFirst = ucwords(strtolower($_POST["guestFirst"]));
$guestFirst = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $guestFirst);


$guestLast =   ucwords(strtolower($_POST["guestLast"]));
$guestLast = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $guestLast);

/**************************FIRST CHILD ***********/
$childFirst_one = ucwords(strtolower($_POST["childFirst_one"]));
$childFirst_one = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $childFirst_one);

$childLast_one =   ucwords(strtolower($_POST["childLast_one"]));
$childLast_one = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $childLast_one);

$childAge_one =   ucwords(strtolower($_POST["childAge_one"]));
$childAge_one = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $childAge_one);

/**************************SECOND CHILD ***********/
$childFirst_two = ucwords(strtolower($_POST["childFirst_two"]));
$childFirst_two = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $childFirst_two);

$childLast_two =   ucwords(strtolower($_POST["childLast_two"]));
$childLast_two = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $childLast_two);

$childAge_two =   ucwords(strtolower($_POST["childAge_two"]));
$childAge_two = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $childAge_two);

/**************************THIRD CHILD ***********/
$childFirst_three = ucwords(strtolower($_POST["childFirst_three"]));
$childFirst_three = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $childFirst_three);

$childLast_three =   ucwords(strtolower($_POST["childLast_three"]));
$childLast_three = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $childLast_three);

$childAge_three =   ucwords(strtolower($_POST["childAge_three"]));
$childAge_three = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $childAge_three);

/**************************THIRD CHILD ***********/
$childFirst_four = ucwords(strtolower($_POST["childFirst_four"]));
$childFirst_four = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $childFirst_four);

$childLast_four =   ucwords(strtolower($_POST["childLast_four"]));
$childLast_four = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $childLast_four);

$childAge_four =   ucwords(strtolower($_POST["childAge_four"]));
$childAge_four = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $childAge_four);


$email =  $_POST["email"];
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $email);


$songRequest = $_POST["songRequest"];
$songRequest = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $songRequest);


//see if record exists
$findEmail = "SELECT * FROM inPerson WHERE email='" . $email."'";
$results = mysqli_query($con, $findEmail);
if(mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0){
    echo "Oops! Looks like you already RSVP'd. Any questions please email us at duanannari@gmail.com :)";
}
else{
    //create SQL statement to create new row;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO inPerson (firstName, lastName, guestFirst, guestLast, childFirst_one, childLast_one, childAge_one, childFirst_two, childLast_two, childAge_two, childFirst_three, childLast_three, childAge_three, childFirst_four, childLast_four, childAge_four, email, songRequest) VALUES ('".$firstName."', '".$lastName."', '".$guestFirst."', '".$guestLast."', '".$childFirst_one."', '".$childLast_one."', '".$childAge_one."', '".$childFirst_two."', '".$childLast_two."', '".$childAge_two."', '".$childFirst_three."', '".$childLast_three."', '".$childAge_three."', '".$childFirst_four."', '".$childLast_four."', '".$childAge_four."', '".$email."', '".$songRequest."');";

    if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
        header("Location: http://www.uyswedding.com/bloemfontein.html");
    }
    else{
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
    }
}

}
else{
if(""!=trim($_POST["spFirstName"])){
    $host = //taken out for security reasons;
    $user = //taken out for security reasons;
    $pass = //taken out for security reasons;
    $db = //taken out for security reasons;
    //connect to database
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

    if (!$con){
        die("Connection failed: " .my_sqli_connect_err());
    }

    //Spirit Vars
    $firstName =  ucwords(strtolower($_POST["spFirstName"]));
    $firstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $firstName);

    $lastName =  ucwords(strtolower($_POST["spLastName"]));
    $lastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $lastName);

    $email =  $_POST["spEmail"];
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $email);

    $spComment =  htmlspecialchars($_POST['spComment']);
    $spComment = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $spComment);


    $findEmail = "SELECT * FROM notAttending WHERE email='" . $email."'";
    $results = mysqli_query($con, $findEmail);                            //137
    if(mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0){                         
        echo "Looks like you have already let us know that you won't be attending! Thanks for being with us in spirit! Any questions please email us at duanannari@gmail.com :)";
    }
    else{
        //create SQL statement to create new row;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO notAttending (spFirstName, spLastName, spEmail, spComment) VALUES ('".$firstName."', '".$lastName."',  '".$email."',  '".$spComment."');";

        if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
            header("Location: http://www.uyswedding.com/aboutus.html");
        }
        else{
           echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
        }
    }

}
```

}
    ?>

Comment: What webserver are you using? You should be able to view the error logs to get specific details of what went wrong and where

Comment: Please read your server's error log. Note also that if [display errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) is off, you're only changing what is written the the server error log - not whether it's output in the html.

Comment: @DarrenH I am using apache server. I am trying to log on to the server via my server provider to see if I can get obtain the error logs

Comment: the logs will either be in /var/log/apache2/ or /var/www/yourwebsitename/log/

Comment: [Thu Jul 23 00:06:41.839198 2015] [:error] [pid 1361] [client ::1:52670] PHP Warning:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /Users/ruys/Sites/rsvpProcess.php on line 137, referer: http://localhost/rsvpForm.html  I have noted line 137 code in main question

Comment: it looks like, your mysqli_query is returning a boolean instead of a mysqli_result. this can happen, when there is no SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN statement in your query. ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) under return values)